# ElasticSearch: rank by proximity to date

Tags: elasticsearch, ranking

In ElasticSearch, is there a way to rank search results by proximity to a given date (or number)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Script Based Sorting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html) to do calculate the proximity. However, if you have a large number of results, your might need to switch to native script to achieve good performance.

Answer (score 0):

try this example:

```
"DECAY_FUNCTION": {
    "FIELD_NAME": {
          "origin": "2013-09-17",
          "scale": "10d",
          "offset": "5d",
          "decay" : 0.5
    }
}
```

DECAY_FUNCTION can be "linear", "exp" and "gauss". If your field is a date field, you can set scale and offset as days, weeks, and so on.

refer: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-function-score-query.html